# Extension Method Limiting The Number Of Linq Results?

Tags: linq, extension-methods, limit

How can I limit the number of results from an extension method on a linq query?

```
var results = db.table.where(a=>a.Id > 500).Limit(10)???
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`IEnumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

```
var results = db.table.where(a=>a.Id > 500).Take(10)
```

**Side note**
If you want to implement paging there is also [`IEnumerable.Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) that can be used to "fast forward" a number of records. Then use like this

```
.Skip(pageNo * pageSize).Take(pageSize)
```

Comment: The method `Skip` is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method `OrderBy` must be called before the method `Skip`.